# ROS not finding installed dependency, 'python-serial'

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to install the 'dynamixel_controllers' package. I have pulled own via the svn and am attempting to 'rosmake'.
I receive this error

```
 Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 35 packages with 0 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/ngs-whitehp/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130718-224424       
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: python-serial Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install dynamixel_tutorials dynamixel_msgs dynamixel_controllers dynamixel_driver`
ngs-whitehp@NGS-whiteHP:~/ros_workspace/dynamixel$ --rosdep-install
--rosdep-install: command not found
ngs-whitehp@NGS-whiteHP:~/ros_workspace/dynamixel$ sudo apt-get install python-serial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-serial is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  nite-dev ps-engine libbluetooth-dev bison evtest gforth
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev python-bluez libusb-dev gforth-common
  joystick flex libffcall1 openni-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 344 not upgraded.
```

Even though 'python-serial' is listed as the newest version, i'm still receiving this warning. This is a 10.04 Ubuntu running Electric (yes, I realize it's an old system but it's necessary that I use this and not upgrade at this moment).

Any suggestions?
I will be controlling Dynamixel Servos from this machine and I assume I will need to be able to communicate to them via Serial... so this is a bit troubling.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67732/ros-not-finding-installed-dependency,-%27python-serial%27/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing to worry about here.  It's telling you that what you asked for is already present so it's not going to install anything.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-07-24**:
So, then, it will "run" when I execute the proper launch commands? (with out an error?